# Not able to access form from controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to check the $valid property of the form in my view:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Form</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="FormController as $ctrl">
    <form name="$ctrl.myForm">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="$ctrl.name">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body> 

</html>
```

My Controller:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app').controller('FormController', formController);

    function formController(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = 'John';
        console.log(vm);
    }
})();
```

My App:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
})();
```

Not sure what the problem is but I keep getting error below:
[image]

***I just tried to print the 'vm' to the console, and I got the below:***
[image]

**How do I access 'myForm' property form the 'vm'?**

Comment: I can't verify at the moment, but I believe you don't need the `$ctrl.` before the form name in your html. It should just be `<form name="myForm">` and then you can access it the way you are attempting to.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkrvqNz0raIn3hH2NNvb?p=preview).

Comment: @georgeawg How do you check if the form is valid or not in the controller?  I tried with 'vm.myForm.$valid' and got error saying that "can not read property '$valid' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you check if the form is valid or not in the controller? I tried with `vm.myForm.$valid` and got error saying that `"can not read property '$valid' of undefined"`.

The [form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) needs a digest cycle to process the `name=$ctrl.myForm` attribute.

Use the `$doCheck` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) to wait:

```
function formController($timeout){
    var vm = this;
    var oldMyForm = false;
    this.$doCheck = function() {
      if (!oldMyForm && vm.myForm) {
        console.log("$valid="+vm.myForm.$valid);
      }
      oldMyForm = vm.myForm;
    };
}
```

From the Docs:

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$doCheck()` - Called on each turn of the digest cycle. Provides an opportunity to detect and act on changes. Any actions that you wish to take in response to the changes that you detect must be invoked from this hook; implementing this has no effect on when `$onChanges` is called. For example, this hook could be useful if you wish to perform a deep equality check, or to check a Date object, changes to which would not be detected by AngularJS's change detector and thus not trigger `$onChanges`. This hook is invoked with no arguments; if detecting changes, you must store the previous value(s) for comparison to the current values.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkrvqNz0raIn3hH2NNvb?p=preview)

---

> I used the `$timeout` instead of `$doCheck` function and it worked too:
>
> ```
> $timeout(function(){ 
>     console.log(vm.myForm.$error); 
> });
> ```

Use of `$timeout` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a larger problem.

In general, controllers should wait for the user to submit forms. Or the controller should react to user input with the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive. In both cases the [form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) will have validated the inputs before the framework invokes either function. Validity should only be checked after user input.

Comment: Thanks, georgeawg!  Now I understand that we need to wait for the digest cycle to process before being able to check the form.  I used the $timeout instead of $doCheck function and it worked too:
$timeout(function(){
            console.log(vm.myForm.$error);
        });